# LACP static on HP Switch with multiple VLAN

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, ieee-802.1ax

I need to connect a 8 interfaces server to a HP J9854A 2530-24G-PoE+-2SFP+ Switch with LACP. Several VLANS are involved. It seems from this link:

http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04777712

in "Table 12 Trunk configuration protocols" that I have to use static LACP because I am in this case : "You want an LACP trunk group to operate in a  LAN other than the default VLAN and GVRP is disabled."

What is the correct configuration for this on the switch?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a trunk with LACP option and tagged VLANS on the trunks.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you configure all the 8 interfaces as one 802.3ad connection (a.k.a. LACP) and had the VLAN connections running over that connection with every packet containing VLAN tag? Did you use "default vlan" or "native vlan" for any network?